# Node.js app "server not available" on amazon instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a node.js app running on an amazon instance (which has ran successfully before my cc exprired and got my instance turned off). Now when I try to go to the instance it says server not available. I've already started mongo/node and all dashboard checks look good. Is there something I'm forgetting?

ec2-54-235-64-205.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Something a long the lines of opening ports on amazon instance nuance or something? I have a custom tcp at port 3000 for node. There must be some "amazon thing" I'm forgetting!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a security group rule inside the management console to allow this to happen.

Further instructions to add the rule through the console can be found [here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

Comment: Hi, I had already added a custom tcp on part 3000 for node and still not working.